# Why is the method not accessed synchronously by the threads in this Java program?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

In this multi-threaded program, threads "t1" and "t2" are trying to execute the synchronized method `printTable()` on the same object obj. When t1 is started and `printTable()` is called from its `run()` method, t2 must wait until t1 has finished executing the synchronized method; why is this not happening? Why is the output unsorted?

Here is the program:

```
class Table{  
        void printTable(int n){//synchronized method  
            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){  
                System.out.println(n*i);  
                try{  
                    //Thread.sleep(400);  
                }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
            }  
        }  
}  

public class TestSynchronization3{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        final Table obj = new Table();//only one object  
            Thread t1=new Thread(){  
                public void run(){  
                    obj.printTable(5);  
                }  
            };  
            Thread t2=new Thread(){  
                public void run(){  
                    obj.printTable(100);  
                }  
            };  
            t1.start();  
            t2.start();  
        }  
}
```

Comment: You never actually use the keyword `synchronized` to declare the method as a synchronous one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the keyword `synchronized` before the`printTable()` method in class `Table` as pointed out by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4967929/michael). Change the signature of the function `printTable()` from

```
 void printTable(int n){...}
```

to

```
 synchronized void printTable(int n){...}
```

This produces the output as:

```
100
200
300
400 
500
5
10
15
20
25
```

or

```
5  
10  
15  
20  
25  
100  
200  
300  
400  
500
```

Answer (score 0):

> why is this not happening? Why is the output unsorted?

Although, as the other comments and answer has mentioned, you need to use the `synchronized` keyword, I suspect that your real problem is that you are not understanding the race conditions with threads.

Just because you are starting the `obj.printTable(5);` thread before the `obj.printTable(100);` thread in your code, this does not ensure that the threads run in that order.  As [@user5794376](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) demonstrates, when the two threads start there is a race to see who is the first one to call `printTable(...)` and who then has to wait for the other thread to finish.  Threads run asynchronously and it is not possible to predict which one will win and guarantee the order.

If you need to force the order of output then the question then becomes, why are you using threads unless this is some sort of academic exercise.  The whole point of threads is that they run in parallel, asynchronously.  Any measures, like lockings or signaling, that is used to control their order of operation invalidates their whole purpose.

Another thing to try is to run `printTable(...)` from the two threads without synchronization at all.  `System.out.println(...)` is a synchronized method so that is fine.  You will probably see the same output however because, again, one thread is getting and running through all 5 of its `println(...)` statements before the other one starts.  If you really want to see interleaving then you should increase the 5 to 5000000.  Then you should see a block of the `*5` output and then a block of the `*100` output.

Hope this helps.